# Magento 1.7 not able to save upsell products

Tags: magento-1.7

I am experiencing a weird problem. 
I have a virtual product in magento, I hit edit, I go to upsell products, select one and hit save. Product is being saved with no errors. If I hit edit again the upsell product I selected before wasn't saved.

Although form submission completes with no errors no data from upsell,related or crosssell tabs is being saved.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to database repair tool, you may have a problem with your DB http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool